# GetDrives and Files Sometimes Failing

Tags: c#

I am recursively entering my computer drives to list all files available. But sometimes the program runs then stops and says it can't access a directory.

What should I do now, I am using win7.

Answer (score 0):

Some of your directories are not readable for your user account. Please show some code or the correct error methods where its throwing exceptions for you.

Comment: The codeis here  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: As already said, those codes are doing much more than just reading a directory like calculating its size, etc. So for that you need read access to all parts of the tree.

Comment: Its your user accounts rights set by the admin. So get the access rights or just skip if you get any exception to the next top directory searching.

Answer (score 0):

Give a read permission to the folder where your driver lies.